# Azure Functions, Deployment Slots and API Management: Function key issue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

so i am currently working in a solution that uses at least one Azure function with authorization level (Function) and consequently uses the Function Key to authorize. I have one deployment slot configured (staging) and i am using CD via VSTS to build , deploy the function and swap slots. All working well.

But now comes the API Management, whereas i have the function registered in the API Management, so end-users in order to interact with the function, they do it via API Management. Consequently in order to the API Management make valid requests, it injects the Function Key in the backend URL request.

But, anytime i deploy a new version of the function, and then i swap, the function key change.

So it requires me to change the function key in the api management as well. Is there any way to avoid the key to change (maybe same key between the production and staging slots ?), or maybe another easier way to work on this?

I am just trying to avoid dependencies, so anytime i deploy a change in the function, i don't need to worry about changing the API Management, specially since it is a manual change.

Thanks

Comment: you can automate this change. Which version of azure function r u using ? keys should not change. it is weird

Comment: Thomas, i am using the following Runtime version: 1.0.11820.0 (latest). See, i have two slots for the function app (production and staging). So, each slot has different keys. So if i deploy a new version of the function to staging, and then i swap staging with production, then when the API management tries to contact the production version of the function, it fails since the key is no longer valid.

Comment: How can i automate this change? using an ARM template? the function key is included as parameter in the inbound rules, on the API configuration under the API management. So that means that my ARM template would need to have all configuration in relation with the APIs being used in the API Management service, right?

Comment: oh so the keys swap ? interesting ... through ARM template you can get the functions key, otherwise there is a key management api for azure function: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Key-management-API

Comment: yeah you can do this or output the function url and inject it into another step of your release pipeline

Comment: yes the keys swap with the slot swap. i was trying to understand if there is a way to persist the same keys, but i did not find it so far.

Comment: yes, but if i use the function url during the function deployment process, then i need to be able to have a step to change the API configuration in the API Management service, in order to the API inbound rules use the new function's url. what kind of step i can use in this case?

Comment: Use a azure powershell step. dont know much around API management but there should be a powershell module to do it ?

Comment: Well, i am going to try to see if the Key Management API allows me to change the Function Key. If yes, then i can create a step to post to the api and specify the function key with the value i want. let me try...

Comment: Yes it looks good, let me try that one as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173221/discussion-between-hugo-barona-and-thomas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Thomas, first of all, thank you so much for the suggestions in relation with the Key Management API and the ARM template. In reality, my findings are: when you use function slots, each slot has its own dedicated keys (default function keys and default host keys). Consequently when you have this scenario, using API Management requesting a function, and relying on those keys, then if you swap slots in the function, the API management will no longer be able to request with success the function. So, in order to avoid creating additional steps in the function's deployment process and so on, i decided to try to create a custom function key (authkey) and associate the same value to both slots. so api management can use that key, independently which slot is the production slot.

Anyway, i am happy with this solution for now in order to avoid any robust custom solution.

Thanks again Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Portal, open your Function App and go to the App Keys section. An App Key can be edited by clicking on the key name. So you can copy the key being used in production, and paste it into the corresponding key value in the other deployment slot. That way, both slots will use the same keys and won't need changing every time you swap.

If you're using Function Keys instead of App Keys, you can copy and paste the keys in the same way.